# Nexus Repo 3 Logging - Log Viewer

Tags: nexus3

As an admin I want to look at the log viewer and monitor what has been downloaded, uploaded, and changed from Origin IP and User ID. But I cannot figure out which default logger Nexus 3 would show this information.

I see in Logging there are Loggers that come with nexus by default.  Their Logger Levels can be set to INFO, ERROR, WARN, DEBUG, TRACE.

I can see that by changing the levels of each Logger I can gain more information.

Does anyone know which logger or how to create a logger that can show IP addresses and User ID when looking at Log Viewer?

[image: Loggers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at /nexus-data/log/request.log, the IP and username should be there